# calling for_each with execution policy par_unseq and yet links without tbb

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, simd, tbb

In a source file called holes5.cpp, I have this code:

cdtt is a Lamda with side effects.

```
for (int depth=0; depth<10; depth++)
{
  auto rng = views::iota(0, (int)decision_tree.size()) |
             views::filter([&](int id){return decision_tree[id].depth==depth;});
  for_each(execution::par_unseq, rng.begin(), rng.end(), cdtt);
}
```

In CMakelists.txt, I have:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "deps/tbb/cmake/")
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
set (SOURCES holes5.cpp)
add_executable(holes5 ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(holes5 PUBLIC TBB::tbb)
```

Now if I comment out

```
target_link_libraries(holes5 PUBLIC TBB::tbb)
```

It still links without error.

On top of that, my machine has 4 cores, and there is zero performance gain from using par_unseq over seq. The result still gets computed normally. It really seems like this call to `for_each()` does not really get parallelized.

I compiled this with G++12.

Comment: Does your code use any TBB library functions?  It looks like C++17 `std::for_each` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) with C++17 `std::execution::par_unseq` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag) on some C++20 `std::views` stuff, so no surprise that there aren't any calls to any TBB library functions.  So even if the compiler did figure out how to actually take advantage of the freedom to parallelize or reorder, TBB isn't involved.

Comment: Also, this isn't a [mcve], you're missing includes.  And missing `std::` in front of most things.  What is this code supposed to do, anyway?  Unclear if it's something a compiler would know how to vectorize or parallelize in the first place.  If not, you wouldn't get a speedup.

Comment: `views::filter` This doesn't seem like something that's going to help parallelization. Filter views are not sized ranges, nor are they random access ranges. That's going to make apportionment of iterators to different threads complicated.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The question was tagged [simd] until you removed it; they also mentioned number of cores, but SIMD filtering is a thing, like ignoring some elements.  Or even left-packing them as in [AVX2 what is the most efficient way to pack left based on a mask?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36932240) (can be done much more efficiently with AVX-512, if you're actually making a filtered output array). You're right that one pass with multiple threads wouldn't be possible, but you could do 2 passes. OTOH, I wouldn't expect a compiler to invent the temporary arrays for it, or even use SIMD in one thread.

Comment: You guys are right. I copied the input to a simple vector of int and passed it to for_each instead of the C++20 std::views stuff, and now linking without tbb is completely impossible. Mystery solved. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of input iterators made from C++20 views prevent calls to tbb.

```
for (int depth=0; depth<10; depth++)
{
  auto rng = views::iota(0, (int)decision_tree.size()) |
             views::filter([&](int id){return decision_tree[id].depth==depth;});
  vector<int> input(rng.begin(), rng.end());
  for_each(execution::par_unseq, input.begin(), input.end(), cdtt);
}
```

Will be properly vectorized and make calls to tbb

Comment: How can one know apriori what calls prevent calls to tbb and which don't?

Comment: If the iterators look really like basic pointer arithmetic, they will not prevent calls to tbb, if they involve more sophisticated algorithm, them probably will.

Comment: So if I have a generic cpu-heavy function I'd like to run on elements of some vector in parallel using for_each, are you saying this won't work unless the function is quite trivial?

Comment: not the function, the iterator on your vector needs to be trivial